# robots.txt blocking crawlers from accesing page

Tags: seo, web-crawler, robots.txt

I try to find how to block crawlers to access my links that are something like this:

site.com/something-search.html

I want to block all /something-*

Can someone help me?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /something-
```

This blocks all URLs whose path starts with `/something-`, for example for a robots.txt accessible from `http://example.com/robots.txt`:

- `http://example.com/something-`
- `http://example.com/something-foo`
- `http://example.com/something-foo.html`
- `http://example.com/something-foo/bar`
- …

The following URLs would still be allowed:

- `http://example.com/something`
- `http://example.com/something.html`
- `http://example.com/something/`
- …

Answer (score 0):

In your robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: site.com/something-(1st link)
.
.
.
Disallow: site.com/somedthing-(last link)
```

Add entry for each page that you don't want to be seen!

Though regex are not allowd in robots.txt some intelligent crawlers can understand it!

have a look [here](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

Comment: The problem is that i cant know what is the first and last link, this is my search result page and i want to disable crawler to access that search page ... i tried with this: Disallow: /search-*
Wildcard characters (like "*") are not allowed here 
The line below must be an allow, disallow, comment or a blank line statement

Comment: No you can not use * in robots.txt

Comment: `Disallow` must not contain the host (`site.com` in your case) of the URLs.